# virtual function doesn't enter to the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I want to know why this function prints "aba h()" and not "son h()", because of its virtual. I thought maybe the function is hiding the other function, but it has the same signature.

```
class Aba: public Saba {
public:
    Aba(){cout << "Aba Ctor" << endl;}
    Aba(const Aba& a){cout << "Aba Copy Ctor" << endl;}
    ~Aba(){cout << "Aba Dtor" << endl;}
    virtual void g(){cout << "Aba g()" << endl;}
    virtual void f(int){cout << "Aba f(int)" << endl;}
    virtual void h(){cout << "Aba h()" << endl;}
};

class Son: public Aba {

public:
    Son(){cout << "Son Ctor" << endl;}
    Son(const Son& a){cout << "Son Copy Ctor" << endl;}
    ~Son(){cout << "Son Dtor" << endl;}
    void f(){cout << "Son f()" << endl;}
    void h(){cout << "Son h()" << endl;}
};
```

main:

```
int main()

{
    Aba aba = Aba();
    aba.h();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is the explicit purpose of virtual functions.  By creating an `Aba`, the `h()` call resolves to `Aba::h`.  Virtual functions are aware of the created type.  Non-virtual function are not.

Comment: Why would this print `Son` anything? You don't reference `Son` in `main()` at all.

Comment: @JohnKugelman you enter to the virtual of the son only when there is ref?

Comment: I'm saying the word `Son` doesn't appear at all inside `main()`. Only `Aba`. So of course none of `Son`'s code is run.

Comment: but it is virtual function and son is the derived class

Comment: But the variable `aba` is not a `Son`. If you did `Aba aba = Son()` then it would print `Son`

Comment: @Barmar: it would call Aba's copy constructor, and a.h() would still print the same message. To call methods polymorphically one should declare a pointer or reference type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`virtual` method is resolved based on the object type being referred to. In your case the object type is **always** `Aba` because even if you assign `Son()`, the object is sliced to `Aba`. Hence it prints the `Aba::h()` method.

Runtime dynamic binding is possible with references & pointers. In below cases it will print `Son::h()`.

```
Son s;
Aba& r = s;
r.h(); // r referres to Son
Aba* p = &r; // or &s
p->h(); // p points/referred to Son
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are calling the function `h` with a static object, therefore the call of this function got resolved at the compile time only, ***it has nothing to do with the function being virtual. Binding of this call has already been done.***

Only in case of dynamic objects, the binding is done at the runtime, looking at which object the pointer is pointing to.

```
Aba *ptr = new Son;
ptr->h(); //Ptr is pointing to Son, hence Son::h() will get called.
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions resolve to the corresponding function of the dynamic type of an object, not the static type as it is with non virtual functions:

```
Aba && one = Aba();
// static type: reference to Aba
// dynamic type of referenced object: Aba
```

Therefore, a virtual function resolves to the function defined as member of `Aba`.

```
Aba && two = Son();
// static type: reference to Aba
// dynamic type of referenced object: Son
```

Now a virtual function will resolve to the definition in `Son`, assuming there is such a definition.